# PGFPlots mesh with end arrow decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-arrows

Inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214974/tikz-path-with-changing-color-and-arrow-decorations) I tried to decorate my PGFPlots mesh with an end arrow. However, this end arrow is not properly positioned so that the end of the line shows behind the arrow tip. Here is a minimal working example. Most of it is copied from [the main answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215039) of the above-mentioned question.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\def\definemappedcolor#1{%
    %\message{Got #1^^J}%
    \pgfmathparse{#1*1000}% ... transform to range [0,1000]
    \pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{\pgfmathresult}%
}%

\tikzset{
  set arrow inside/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/arrow inside}{#1}},
  set arrow inside={end/.initial=>, opt/.initial=},
  /pgf/decoration/Mark/.style={
    mark/.expanded=at position #1 with
    {
      \noexpand\definemappedcolor{#1}%
      \noexpand\arrow[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/opt}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/end}}
    }
  },
  arrow inside/.style 2 args={
    set arrow inside={#1},
    postaction={
      decorate,decoration={
        markings,Mark/.list={#2}
      }
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x=1cm, y=1cm, colormap/hot, point meta=explicit]
    \addplot[mesh] 
        coordinates {
        (0,0) [0]
        (1,1) [1]
        (2,2) [2]
        (3,3) [3]
        (4,2) [4]
    };

    \addplot[draw=none] 
        coordinates {
        (0,0) [0]
        (1,1) [1]
        (2,2) [2]
        (3,3) [3]
        (4,2) [4]
    } [arrow inside={end=stealth,opt={mapped color, scale=3}}{1}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

As you can clearly see, the arrow tip is not properly attached to the end of the plot, but rather slightly before the end. I have tried to make use of `shorten >=2pt`, but it does not seem to work.

**How can I position the arrow so that it is "properly" attached to the end of the plot line, i.e., how can I prevent the end of the line to be seen?**

Comment: You mean that the "base" of the arrow tip should be touching the very end of the plot line and not be over it?

Comment: It is placed properly. But the line end is square and arrow tip is sharp. Hence at the end the line is seen. Adjust the coordinates in `draw=none` line like `(4.02,1.98) [4]` you will see the difference.

Comment: Otherwise put, how can I prevent the end of the line to be seen (without changing the coordinates, of course)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that you draw the arrow on top of "whatever previously was
drawn". That is why there is no "auto-correction" of this behavior as it would
be the case when you would apply the arrow to the line directly.

To "simulate" that behavior you can draw a double-arrow. The first just
overdraws the parts of the "other" line that should not be seen and the second
being the "real" arrow what you wanted to add. To do so you have to use a
negative separation length.

In addition I tried to find a solution that is independent of the chosen
line width and is tested for line width up to `ultra thick'.

For more details have a look at the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        % load this library to make use of the advanced arrow features
        arrows.meta,
        decorations.markings,
        pgfplots.colormaps,
    }

\def\definemappedcolor#1{%
    %\message{Got #1^^J}%
    \pgfmathparse{#1*1000}% ... transform to range [0,1000]
    \pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{\pgfmathresult}%
}%

\tikzset{
    set arrow inside/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/arrow inside}{#1}},
    set arrow inside={end/.initial=>, opt/.initial=},
    /pgf/decoration/Mark/.style={
        mark/.expanded=at position #1 with {
            \noexpand\definemappedcolor{#1}%
            \noexpand\arrow[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/opt}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/end}}
        }
    },
    arrow inside/.style 2 args={
        set arrow inside={#1},
        postaction={
            decorate,decoration={
                markings,Mark/.list={#2}
            },
        },
    },
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    my arrow/.tip={
        % this arrow tip shall overdraw the end of the "other" draw line
        Rectangle[
            % scale this arrow to 5 times the length of `line width'
            % (you can adjust this; it must only be longer than the "free" seen
            %  stuff of the "other" line)
            % and (only) being as width as `line width'
            length={0pt 5},
            width={0pt 1},
            % now adjust the `sep' to make it independent of line width
            sep={-3.05pt -5},
            % assume white background color
%            white,
            green,  % for debugging purposes only
        ]
        % and this is the arrow you actually want to plot
        Stealth[]
    },
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        x=1cm,
        y=1cm,
        colormap/hot,
        point meta=explicit,
    ]
        \addplot [
            mesh,
            % make (already) active to prove that I didn't move the line or arrow tip
            very thick,
        ] coordinates {
            (0,0) [0]
            (1,1) [1]
            (2,2) [2]
            (3,3) [3]
            (4,2) [4]
        };

        \addplot [
            draw=none,
            % make sure, this has the same `line width' as the previous plot
%            very thick,
        ]
            coordinates {
            (0,0) [0]
            (1,1) [1]
            (2,2) [2]
            (3,3) [3]
            (4,2) [4]
        % apply the defined arrow here
        } [arrow inside={end=my arrow}{1}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the zoomed result of above code]