# Plot Schmitt-Trigger Hysteresis

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to plot an hysteresis of a Schmitt-Trigger. The following figure shows the desired graph.

[image: Schmitt-Trigger Hysteresis]

How can I achive this using *pgfplots*? I have the minimum and maximum of both axis values as known dimensions.

**Edit:** I came up with something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [ylabel={$U_y [V]$},
    xlabel={$U_x [V]$},
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    minor y tick num=1,
    grid=major,
    legend entries={{$R_1 = R_2 = 470 k\Omega$}
    ,{$R_1 = 1 k\Omega, R_2 = 4,7 k\Omega$},
    {$R_1 = 470 \Omega, R_2 = 10 k\Omega$}},
    legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot[mark=none,red] coordinates {(-8,-8) (4,-8) (4,8) (8,8) (-4,8) (-4,-8)};
\addplot[mark=none,brown] coordinates {(-8,-8) (1.4,-8) (1.4,8) (8,8) (-1.4,8) (-1.4,-8)};
\addplot[mark=none,blue] coordinates {(-8,-8) (0.3,-8) (0.3,8) (8,8) (-0.3,8) (-0.3,-8)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: latex preview of plot]

Comment: Have you made any attempt so far? If so please post whatever code you have.

Comment: Drawing this in pure `tikz` is more simple than in `pgfplots`.

Comment: @Null Added my attempts, no arrows so far and I wonder if transparancy could help in displaying the different plots more clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can investigate with `pgfplots` marks, but `decorations.markings` can serve to draw arrows.

What I've done is keeping your pgfplots draw but adding a `draw` command which will repeat lines but adding arrow decorations on them. I've tried adding decorations to `\addplot` commands but they also apply to lines in legend.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\tikzset{myarrows/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={markings,
        mark=at position .04 with {\arrowreversed{Latex}},
        mark=at position .1 with {\arrow{Latex}},
        mark=at position .2 with {\arrow{Latex}},
        mark=at position .6 with {\arrow{Latex}}
    }}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}
    [ylabel={$U_y [V]$},
    xlabel={$U_x [V]$},
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    minor y tick num=1,
    grid=major,
    legend entries={{$R_1 = R_2 = 470 k\Omega$}
    ,{$R_1 = 1 k\Omega, R_2 = 4,7 k\Omega$},
    {$R_1 = 470 \Omega, R_2 = 10 k\Omega$}},
    legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot[mark=none,red] coordinates {(-8,-8) (4,-8) (4,8) (8,8) (-4,8) (-4,-8)};
\addplot[mark=none,brown] coordinates {(-8,-8) (1.4,-8) (1.4,8) (8,8) (-1.4,8) (-1.4,-8)};
\addplot[mark=none,blue] coordinates {(-8,-8) (0.3,-8) (0.3,8) (8,8) (-0.3,8) (-0.3,-8)};

\draw[red,myarrows](-8,-8)-|(4,8);
\draw[red,myarrows] (8,8)-|(-4,-8);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

I've found an [answer from Christian Feuersänger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215039/1952) to [Tikz path with changing color and arrow decorations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214974/tikz-path-with-changing-color-and-arrow-decorations) which can be used to draw arrows with a `addplot` command. It uses `markings` decoration with a list of points where to place the arrow tips with options to fix kind of arrow, color, scale, ...

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\tikzset{
  set arrow inside/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/arrow inside}{#1}},
  set arrow inside={end/.initial=>, opt/.initial=},
  /pgf/decoration/Mark/.style={
    mark/.expanded=at position #1 with
    {
      \noexpand\arrow[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/opt}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/end}}
    }
  },
  arrow inside/.style 2 args={
    set arrow inside={#1},
    postaction={
      decorate,decoration={
        markings,Mark/.list={#2}
      }
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}
    [ylabel={$U_y [V]$},
    xlabel={$U_x [V]$},
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    minor y tick num=1,
    grid=major,
    legend entries={{$R_1 = R_2 = 470 k\Omega$}
    ,{$R_1 = 1 k\Omega, R_2 = 4,7 k\Omega$},
    {$R_1 = 470 \Omega, R_2 = 10 k\Omega$}},
    legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot[mark=none,brown] coordinates {(-8,-8) (1.4,-8) (1.4,8) (8,8) (-1.4,8) (-1.4,-8) (-8,-8)};
\addplot[mark=none,blue] coordinates {(-8,-8) (0.3,-8) (0.3,8) (8,8) (-0.3,8) (-0.3,-8) (-8,-8)};
\addplot[mark=none,red] coordinates {(-8,-8) (4,-8) (4,8) (8,8) (-4,8) (-4,-8) (-8,-8)};

\addplot[draw=none,red] coordinates {(-8,-8) (4,-8) (4,8) (8,8) (-4,8) (-4,-8) (-8,-8)} [arrow inside={end=Latex, opt={red, scale=1.5}}{0.04,0.25,0.49,0.54,0.75,0.99}];
\addplot[draw=none,brown] coordinates {(-8,-8) (1.4,-8) (1.4,8) (8,8) (-1.4,8) (-1.4,-8) (-8,-8)} [arrow inside={end=Latex, opt={brown, scale=1.5}}{0.22,0.72}];
\addplot[draw=none,blue] coordinates {(-8,-8) (0.3,-8) (0.3,8) (8,8) (-0.3,8) (-0.3,-8) (-8,-8)} [arrow inside={end=Latex, opt={blue, scale=1.5}}{0.22,0.72}];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks not that bad, but colored arrows would be better I think. Anyway, nice solution.

Comment: @maxik I've updated the answer with a solution better integrated with `pgfplots` and easily customizable arrows. Hope it helps.

Comment: Well done! I will add some transparency and look if this helps the appearence.